# what wrong in this file it shows me indentation error?(its not working help please)

Tags: python, mysql, database, project, mysql-connector-python

```
import os
import platform
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import datetimeenter code here
global z
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
 host='localhost',
 database='hotel')
mycursor=mydb.cursor()

def registercust():
  L=[]
  name=input("enter name:")
  L.append(name)
  addr=input("enter address:")
  L.append(addr)
  indate=input("enter check in date:")
  L.append(indate)
  outdate=input("enter check out date:")
  L.append(outdate)
  cust=(L)
  sql="insert into custdata(name,addr,indate,outdate)values(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
  mycursor.execute(sql,cust)
  mydb.commit()
def roomtypeview():
  print("Do yoy want to see room type available : Enter 1 for yes :")
  ch=int(input("enter your choice:"))
  if ch==1:
      sql="select * from roomtype"
      mycursor.execute(sql)
      rows=mycursor.fetchall()
      for x in rows:
        print(x)
def roomrent():
     print ("We have the following rooms for you:-")
     print ("1. type A---->rs 1000 PN\-")
     print ("2. type B---->rs 2000 PN\-")
     print ("3. type C---->rs 3000 PN\-")
     print ("4. type D---->rs 4000 PN\-")
     x=int(input("Enter Your Choice Please->"))
     n=int(input("For How Many Nights Did You Stay:"))
 if(x==1):
    print ("you have opted room type A")
    s=1000*n
 elif (x==2):
    print ("you have opted room type B")
    s=2000*n
 elif (x==3):
    print ("you have opted room type C")
    s=3000*n
 elif (x==4):
    print ("you have opted room type D")
    s=4000*n
 else:
    print ("please choose a room")
 print ("your room rent is =",s,"\n")
def restaurentmenuview():
  print("Do yoy want to see mebu available : Enter 1 for yes :")
  ch=int(input("enter your choice:"))
  if ch==1:
      sql="select * from restaurent"
      mycursor.execute(sql)
      rows=mycursor.fetchall()
      for x in rows:
        print(x)
def orderitem():
  global s
  print("Do yoy want to see mebu available : Enter 1 for yes :")
  ch=int(input("enter your choice:"))
  if ch==1:
       sql="select * from restaurent"
       mycursor.execute(sql)
       rows=mycursor.fetchall()
       for x in rows:
          print(x)
 
 print("do you want to purchase from above list:enter your choice:")
 d=int(input("enter your choice:"))
 if(d==1):
    print("you have ordered tea")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=10*a
    print("your amount for tea is :",s,"\n")
 elif (d==2):
    print("you have ordered coffee")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=10*a
    print("your amount for coffee is :",s,"\n")
 elif(d==3):
    print("you have ordered colddrink")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=20*a
    print("your amount for colddrink is :",s,"\n")
 elif(d==4):
    print("you have ordered samosa")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=10*a
    print("your amount fopr samosa is :",s,"\n")
 elif(d==5):
    print("you have ordered sandwich")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=50*a
    print("your amount fopr sandwich is :",s,"\n")
 elif(d==6):
    print("you have ordered dhokla")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=30*a
    print("your amount for dhokla is :",s,"\n")
 elif(d==7):
    print("you have ordered kachori")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=10*a
    print("your amount for kachori is :",s,"\n")
 elif(d==8):
    print("you have ordered milk")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=20*a
    print("your amount for kachori is :",s,"\n")
 elif(d==9):
    print("you have ordered noodles")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=50*a
    print("your amount for noodles is :",s,"\n")
 elif(d==10):
    print("you have ordered pasta")
    a=int(input("enter quantity"))
    s=50*a
    print("your amount for pasta is :",s,"\n")
 else:
    Print("please enter your choice from the menu")
def laundarybill():
  global z
  print("Do yoy want to see rate for laundary : Enter 1 for yes :")
  ch=int(input("enter your choice:"))
  if ch==1:
      sql="select * from laundary"
      mycursor.execute(sql)
      rows=mycursor.fetchall()
      for x in rows:
         print(x)
    y=int(input("Enter Your number of clothes->"))
    z=y*10
    print("your laundary bill:",z,"\n")
    return z
def lb():
  print(z)
def res():
  print(s)
def viewbill():
  a=input("enter customer name:")
  print("customer name :",a,"\n")
  print("laundarey bill:")
  print(lb)
  print("restaurent bill:")
  print(res)
 
def Menuset():
  print("enter 1: To enter customer data")
  print("enter 2 : To view roomtype")
  print("enter 3 : for calculating room bill")
  print("enter 4 : for viewing restaurent menu")
  print("enter 5 : for restaurent bill")
  print("enter 6 :for laundary bill")
  print("enter 7 : for complete bill")
  print("enter 8 : for exit:")
  try:
    userinput=int(input("pleaseselect an above option:"))
 except ValueError:
   exit("\n hi thats not a number")
 
 userinput=int(input("enter your choice"))
 if(userinput==1):
    registercust()
 elif(userinput==2):
    roomtypeview()
 elif(userinput==3):
    roomrent()
 elif(userinput==4):
    restaurentmenuview()
 elif(userinput==5):
    orderitem()
 elif(userinput==6):
    laundarybill()
 elif(userinput==7):
    viewbill()
 elif(userinput==8):
    quit()
 else:
   print("enter correct choice")
Menuset()
def runagain():
 runagn=input("\n want to run again y/n:")
 while(runagn.lower()=='y'):
  if(platform.system()=="windows"):
     print(os.system('cls'))
   else:
     print(os.system('clear'))
    Menuset()
    runagn=input("\n want to run again y/n:")
runagain()
```

it shows indentation error I also have its mysql database but it is not connecting to it. this is from my school project but i have no one to solve this problem so please review it and tell me about the error                                                                                                                                                         .               .

Comment: The issue seems to be that the try/except block is misaligned. (Although I am getting a SyntaxError not an IndentationError for that)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line 7,8,9,10 with the code below:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
host='localhost'
database='hotel'
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the indentation on line 8 , 9 just remove the first white space on that line and use an IDE your code is full of mistakes you should learn the basics rather than copying the code from somewhere

Comment: No that is not the problem, it's a function call continued from the line before.

Comment: You havent put the closing brackets at the end of function

Comment: There are closing brackets there

Comment: Thats not how it works